# callback from directive, work with updated object?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

[See my plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5DfEgRYinoeG5uZ9dVvE?p=info), with angular 1.0.8.

I'd like to work with the updated object in my controller method (fired by the directive callback).

This is the current situation:
[image]

Is there a way to work on the updated object somehow? (the directive is used all over the website, its meant to be very generic)

Comment: my question includes valid code, weird 'close' reasons...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because the value is not being tracked. You can't use a primitive type for model if you want the value to be monitored in digest cycle since AngularJS requires an object type to track the change by its prototype.

Change the model to this and the code will work correctly.

```
  $scope.preferences =
    foo: {value: true}
    bar: {value: true}
    baz: {value: true}


  link: (scope)->
    scope.clicked = ->
      scope.model.value = !scope.model.value
      scope.callback({ value: scope.model })
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/UhB9qK5M1X6vvv6XrKFf?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: interesting approach, +1

Comment: @apneadiving The common rule of AngularJS is to always use `references`, there is no magic behind the scene.

Comment: @apneadiving I just saw the question you asked early today, same problem. You should be able to fix it. Everything relating to `$digest` can be ignored for your questions since it is unrelated. You only need to call `scope.$apply` if the change is made **OUTSIDE** AngularJS's scope.

Comment: yes it is the same problem, but js objects represent models and its pretty intrusive to change everything to references

Answer (score -1):

You are using an isolated scope so the value is updating, just not propagating to the parent scope until later in the digest cycle.  If in your above example you click 'Foo', you can see that bar is false in both.  I don't know how you can queue your callback until the rest of angular binding is done since you need access to other scope elements in your callback, but you can use $timeout ([plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nni68Lk830R2Q3k3FMXl?p=preview)):

```
app.directive 'myCheckbox', ($timeout) ->
...
  scope.clicked = ->
    scope.model = !scope.model
    fn = ->
      scope.callback({ value: scope.model })
    $timeout fn, 1
```

Comment: please timeouts are not an option